# ¿cómo eliminar de datatable sin que solicite diligenciar datos del formulario?

Tags: html, primefaces

Buenas noches, 
tengo un problema al momento de eliminar un atributo del datatable al momento de seleccionarlo en el datatable  y presionar en el boton eliminar me solicita diligenciar los datos del formulario que son requeridos, 
alguien sabe como des habilitarlos para el botón eliminar,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Codigo:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
 xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
 xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
 xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<head>

<title>Cajero</title>
</head>

<ui:composition template="templates/commonLayout.xhtml">
 <title>Cajero</title>
 <ui:define name="cajero">
  <h:outputText value="!!!Gestión de cajero" />
 </ui:define>
 <ui:define name="contenido">
  <h:form id="principal" responsive="true">

   <p:growl id="capaMensajes" globalOnly="false" showSumary="true"
    showDetail="false" autoUpdate="true" closable="true" />



   <p:fieldset class="main" legend="Formulario cajero" toggleable="true"
    style="width:90%" toggleSpeed="500">

    <p:toolbar>
     <f:facet name="right">

      <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-refresh" value="Limpiar">
       <p:ajax update="principal" resetValues="true" />
      </p:commandButton>


      <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-disk" value="Crear" id="cbCrear"
       action="#{cajeroBean.crear()}"
       update=":tabla:idTablaCajero,pgCajero" resetValues="principal">


      </p:commandButton>

      <p:blockUI block="principal" trigger="cbCrear">
              Cargando<br />
       <p:graphicImage
        url="images/ajax-loader.gif.pagespeed.ce.VLDv-_-pOi.gif"
        width="80%" />
      </p:blockUI>
      <p:commandButton value="Actualizar" id="cbActualizar"
       action="#{cajeroBean.actualizar}" update=":tabla:idTablaCajero"
       icon="ui-icon-arrowrefresh-1-w">

       <p:confirm header="Actualizar Registro"
        message="¿Está seguro que desea actualizar la informacion del cajero"
        icon="ui-icon-alert" />
      </p:commandButton>

      <p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="fade"
       hideEffect="explode">
       <p:commandButton value="Aceptar" type="button"
        style="font-size:11px" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes"
        icon="ui-icon-check" />
       <p:commandButton value="Cancelar" type="button"
        style="font-size:11px" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no"
        icon="ui-icon-close" />
       <p:blockUI block="principal" trigger="cbActualizar">
              Cargando<br />
        <p:graphicImage
         url="images/ajax-loader.gif.pagespeed.ce.VLDv-_-pOi.gif"
         width="80%" />
       </p:blockUI>
      </p:confirmDialog>

      <p:commandButton value="Eliminar" id="cbEliminar"
       action="#{cajeroBean.eliminar()}"
       update=":tabla:idTablaCajero,pgCajero" icon="ui-icon-trash">
       <p:confirm header="Eliminar Registro"
        message="¿Está seguro que desea eliminar el medio de pago?"
        icon="ui-icon-alert" />
      </p:commandButton>

      <p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="fade"
       hideEffect="explode">
       <p:commandButton value="Aceptar" type="button"
        style="font-size:11px" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes"
        icon="ui-icon-check" />
       <p:commandButton value="Cancelar" type="button"
        style="font-size:11px" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no"
        icon="ui-icon-close" />
      </p:confirmDialog>
      <p:blockUI block="principal" trigger="cbEliminar">
              Cargando<br />
       <p:graphicImage
        url="images/ajax-loader.gif.pagespeed.ce.VLDv-_-pOi.gif"
        width="80%" />
      </p:blockUI>

     </f:facet>

    </p:toolbar>

    <p:panelGrid columns="4" rows="2" responsive="true" align="center"
     id="pgCajero" style="width:100%">



     <h:outputLabel for="itNumeroIdentificacion"
      value="Numero de identificación:" />

     <p:inputText id="itNumeroIdentificacion"
      value="#{cajeroBean.idCodigo}" style="width:150px"
      requiredMessage="La Identificación es requerida">
      <p:message for="itNumeroIdentificacion" display="icon" />

      <p:tooltip for="itNumeroIdentificacion"
       value="Campo para ingresar el numero de identificación"
       hideEffect="explode" />

     </p:inputText>




     <h:outputLabel for="itPrimerNombre" value="Primer nombre:" />

     <p:inputText id="itPrimerNombre" style="width:150px" maxlength="50"
      value="#{cajeroBean.nvPrimerNombre}" required="true"
      requiredMessage="el nombre es requerido">
      <p:message for="itPrimerNombre" display="icon" />
      <p:tooltip for="itPrimerNombre"
       value="Campo para ingresar el primer nombre" hideEffect="explode" />

     </p:inputText>

     <h:outputLabel for="itSegundoNombre" value="Segundo nombre:" />

     <p:inputText id="itSegundoNombre" style="width:150px"
      value="#{cajeroBean.nvSegundoNombre}">

      <p:tooltip for="itSegundoNombre"
       value="Campo para ingresar el Segundo nombre"
       hideEffect="explode" />

     </p:inputText>

     <h:outputLabel for="itPrimerApellido" value="Primer apellido:" />

     <p:inputText id="itPrimerApellido" style="width:150px"
      maxlength="50" value="#{cajeroBean.nvPrimerApellido}"
      required="true" requiredMessage="el primer apellido es requerido">
      <p:message for="itPrimerApellido" display="icon" />



      <p:tooltip for="itPrimerApellido"
       value="Campo para ingresar el primer Apellido"
       hideEffect="explode" />

     </p:inputText>

     <h:outputLabel for="itSegundoApellido" value="Segundo apellido:" />
     <p:inputText id="itSegundoApellido" maxlength="50"
      value="#{cajeroBean.nvSegundoApellido}" style="width:150px">
      <p:tooltip for="itSegundoApellido"
       value="Campo para ingresar el Segundo Apellido:"
       hideEffect="explode" />

     </p:inputText>

     <p:outputLabel for="button" value="Fecha de nacimiento:" />

     <p:calendar id="button" value="#{cajeroBean.date3}" locale="de"
      navigator="true" pattern="d-MM-yyyy" showOn="button"
      required="true"
      requiredMessage="la fecha de nacimiento es requerido" />


     <p:outputLabel for="itTeléfono" value="Teléfono: " />
     <p:inputMask id="itTeléfono" value="#{cajeroBean.intelefono}"
      mask="9999999" style="width:130px"/>




     <p:outputLabel for="genero" value="Genero: " />

     <p:selectOneMenu id="genero" value="#{cajeroBean.genero}" filter="true"
      required="true" requiredMessage="El campo genero es requerido">
      <f:selectItem itemLabel="seleccione el genero" itemValue=""
       noSelectionOption="true" />
      <f:selectItems value="#{cajeroBean.listagenero}" var="g"
       itemValue="#{g.inCodigo}" itemLabel="#{g.nvDescripcion}" />
     </p:selectOneMenu>









    </p:panelGrid>
   </p:fieldset>

  </h:form>

  <p:fieldset collapsed="true" class="main" legend="Listado de cajeros"
   toggleable="true" toggleSpeed="500" style="width:90%">


   <h:form id="tabla" responsive="true">

    <p:dataTable var="cajero" scrollable="true" scrollHeight="100"
     responsive="true" id="idTablaCajero"
     value="#{cajeroBean.listacajero}" widgetVar="tablacajero"
     selectionMode="single" selection="#{cajeroBean.cajero}"
     rowKey="#{cajero.idCodigo}" rows="5" paginator="true"
     paginatorPosition="bottom" rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15"
     draggableColumns="true"
     emptyMessage="No existe Descripción de tipo de pago para mostrar">
     <f:facet name="header">
      <h1></h1>
      <p:commandButton id="toggler" type="button" value="Filtrar"
       style="float" icon="ui-icon-calculator" />
      <p:columnToggler datasource="idTablaCajero" trigger="toggler" />
     </f:facet>
     <p:ajax event="rowSelect" update=":principal:pgCajero" />
     <p:column filterBy="#{cajero.idCodigo}"
     sortBy="#{cajero.idCodigo}"
      headerText=" Identificación" filterMatchMode="contains">
      <h:outputText value="#{cajero.idCodigo}" />
     </p:column>

     <p:column filterBy="#{cajero.nvPrimerNombre}"
     sortBy="#{cajero.nvPrimerNombre}"
      headerText="Primer  Nombre" filterMatchMode="contains">
      <h:outputText value="#{cajero.nvPrimerNombre}" />
     </p:column>
     <p:column filterBy="#{cajero.nvSegundoNombre}"
     sortBy="#{cajero.nvSegundoNombre}"
      headerText="Segundo Nombre" filterMatchMode="contains">
      <h:outputText value="#{cajero.nvSegundoNombre}" />
     </p:column>


     <p:column filterBy="#{cajero.nvPrimerApellido}"
     sortBy="#{cajero.nvPrimerApellido}"
      headerText="Primer  Apellido" filterMatchMode="contains">
      <h:outputText value="#{cajero.nvPrimerApellido}" />
     </p:column>
     <p:column filterBy="#{cajero.nvSegundoApellido}"
     sortBy="#{cajero.nvSegundoApellido}"
      headerText="Segundo Apellido" filterMatchMode="contains">
      <h:outputText value="#{cajero.nvSegundoApellido}" />
     </p:column>


     <p:column filterBy="#{cajero.inTelefono}" headerText="Teléfono"
      filterMatchMode="contains">
      <h:outputText value="#{cajero.inTelefono}"/>
      
     
     </p:column>





    </p:dataTable>
   </h:form>
  </p:fieldset>



 </ui:define>

</ui:composition>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

he encontrado una solución agregando la propiedad : process="@this" 
el código quedaría de la siguiente forma :

```html
<p:commandButton value="Eliminar" id="cbEliminar"
       action="#{cajeroBean.eliminar()}" process="@this"
       update=":tabla:idTablaCajero,pgCajero" icon="ui-icon-trash">
       <p:confirm header="Eliminar Registro"
        message="¿Está seguro que desea eliminar el medio de pago?"
        icon="ui-icon-alert" />
      </p:commandButton>
```